# Dynamically change form post action on submit

Tags: forms

I am trying to have my form change post action dynamically based on a choice made in a dropdown once the user presses submit. i have gotten it to work once the choice is made, but that overrides my validation rules.

the url of the site I am working on is instaloan.glidewebdesign.com

based on a choice from the "Car Title Status" dropdown, I would like it submit a different post action based on the answer.

Thanks in advance for any and all help!!!!!!

```
function set_form_action()
{
    if (page == 'clear_title')
    {
        window.location = 'https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?   Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.com/index.php/thank-you';
    }
    else if (page == 'lien_on_title')
    {
        window.location = 'https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.com/index.php/thank-you2';
    }
    else if (page == 'no_title')
    {
        window.location = 'https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.com/index.php/thank-you3';
    }
}


<form name="homeform" >

            <fieldset>
                            <input name="first" type="text" class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;First Name" maxlength="10" onkeyup="checkInput2(this)" required="required" />
                            <input name="last" type="text" class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;Last Name" maxlength="15" onkeyup="checkInput2(this)" required="required" /></br>
                            <input name="phone" type='tel'    pattern='^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$' title='Phone Number (Format:  (999) 999-9999)' class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;Phone Number" maxlength="10"     onkeyup="checkInput(this)" required="required" />
                            <input name="zip" type="text"     name="zipCode" value=""
   pattern="[0-9]{5}([-][0-9]{4})?" placeholder="&nbsp;Zip Code" class="name"     maxlength="5" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" required="required"  /></br>
                            <select name="amount" class="dropdown" value="Amount Requested">
                                <option value="0">Amount</option>
                                <option value="$100-$499">$100 - $499</option>
                                <option value="$500-$999">$500 - $999</option>
                                <option value="$1000-$1999">$1,000 - $1,999</option>
                                <option value="$2000-$2999">$2,000 - $2,999</option>
                                <option value="$3000+">$3,000+</option>
                        </select>
                            </br>
                            <select name="status" class="dropdown" value="Car Title Status" >
                                <option value="smt">Car Title Status</option>
                                <option value="clear_title">I have a clear car title</option>
                                <option value="lien_on_title">There&#8242;s a lien against my car title</option>
                                <option value="no_title">I don&#8242;t have a car title</option>
                            </select>
                            </br>
                            <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Find Out Now" />
                    </fieldset>

    </form>
```

Comment: Could you post your form and javascript code here for people to review?

Comment: @DanSullivan sorry for the delay in adding my code, I had a family emergency this weekend that kept me away form the computer...

Answer (score 0):

OK...after pulling out the little hair I have left, I got it figured out...waht I was doing was completely wrong, for what I am trying to accomplish anyway. This is my final working code:

```
$("#homeform").submit(function(){
    if($("#status").val() == "clear_title"){
        $(this).attr("action","https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?    Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.co    m/index.php/thank-you");   
    }
   else if($("#status").val() == "lien_on_title"){
        $(this).attr("action","https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?    Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.co    m/index.php/thank-you2");   
    } 
    else if($("#status").val() == "no_title"){
        $(this).attr("action","https://secure.leads360.com/Import.aspx?    Provider=TMXFinance&Client=TMXFinance&CampaignId=1034&Url=http://instaloan.glidewebdesign.co    m/index.php/thank-you3");  
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="homeform" name="homeform" method="post" action="">

                <fieldset>
                            <input name="first" type="text" class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;First Name" maxlength="10" onkeyup="checkInput2(this)" required="required" />
                            <input name="last" type="text" class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;Last Name" maxlength="15" onkeyup="checkInput2(this)" required="required" /></br>
                            <input id="phone" name="phone" type='tel' pattern='^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$' title='Phone Number (Format: (999) 999-9999)' class="name" placeholder="&nbsp;Phone Number" maxlength="10"  required="required" />
                            <input name="zip" type="text" name="zipCode" value=""
   pattern="[0-9]{5}([-][0-9]{4})?" placeholder="&nbsp;Zip Code" class="name"     maxlength="5" onkeyup="checkInput(this)" required="required"  /></br>
                        <select name="amount" class="dropdown" value="Amount Requested">
                            <option value="0">Amount</option>
                            <option value="$100-$499">$100 - $499</option>
                            <option value="$500-$999">$500 - $999</option>
                            <option value="$1000-$1999">$1,000 - $1,999</option>
                            <option value="$2000-$2999">$2,000 - $2,999</option>
                            <option value="$3000+">$3,000+</option>
                        </select>
                        </br>
                        <select id="status" name="status" class="dropdown" value="Car Title Status" >
                            <option value="smt">Car Title Status</option>
                            <option value="clear_title">I have a clear car title</option>
                            <option value="lien_on_title">There&#8242;s a lien against my car title</option>
                            <option value="no_title">I don&#8242;t have a car title</option>
                        </select>
                        </br>
                        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="submit" value="Find Out Now" />
                </fieldset>

</form>
```